# building pytables on mac os lion

Tags: python, hdf5, pytables

I'm trying to build pytables 2.3.1 on mac lion, but I've faced with this error:

> tsf-wpa-3-6133:tables-2.3.1 Hesam$ python setup.py build
>   * Found numpy 1.5.1 package installed.
>   * Found numexpr 1.4.2 package installed.
>   * Found Cython 0.15.1 package installed. .. ERROR:: Could not find a local HDF5 installation.    You may need to explicitly state where
>   your local HDF5 headers and    library can be found by setting the
>   `HDF5_DIR` environment    variable or by using the `--hdf5`
>   command-line option.

Do you know what's the solution?

Thanks.

Comment: maybe this can help: http://assorted-experience.blogspot.com/2011/12/mac-os-x-install-pytables-and-h5py.html for me it still did not work though, I got an error about a missing stdarg.h when using the --hdf5=... argument

Answer (score 2):

I built PyTables successfully on Mac OSX 10.7 today. Wrote a blog post:
http://ericjang.tumblr.com/post/25096909713/annoying-pytables-build-on-mac-osx-10-7

Hope it helps!

Comment: the trick is to specify --prefix=/usr/local/ when running the ./configure script

Answer (score 0):

If you do the following, I think you can install it successfully:

1. brew install hdf5
2. install c-blosc(https://github.com/Blosc/c-blosc/).